# Very simple XSLT string question

Tags: xslt

How would I do "substring(variable,1,1) between a-z or A-Z" then do X else do Y using XSLT? I know that one option would be using regex but I would expect there to be something that wasn't quite so much overkill.

Comment: Hmmh. Why would regex be an overkill? XSLT itself is heavy-weight enough that I think there's no need to be concerned about use of REs.
Good processors should pre-compile them anyway, if possible.

Comment: Am I following correctly that you want to make sure that the first character of a string variable is an upper or lowercase letter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A simple XSLT 1.0 solution**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLetters"
  select="'ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vText" select="'1Text'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=
          "contains($vLetters, substring($vText,1,1))">
            Letter
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          Not Letter
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document (not used),
produces the wanted result**:

```
      Not Letter
```

Depending on the specific case one can add whatever processing is necessary to each of the two "clauses" (`<xsl:when>` and `<xsl:otherwise>`) of the `<xsl:choose>` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

And for XSLT 2.0, you can use the regular expression function `matches`:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="matches($variable1, '^[a-zA-Z].*$')">
    Match
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   NoMatch
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: XSLT 2.0 has, among other disadvantages, the disadvantage that I can't do quick and dirty transform tests in whatever browser I want.

Comment: Agreed. I tend to use XSLT 1.0 for the same reason.